# npm install error npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-79-generic-pae

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, ubuntu

I have a problem with my node and will not let me install .

```
armikhael@armikhael-MB40II:~/github/base-angular$ sudo npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-79-generic-pae
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0`
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
```

Comment: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/403 Please walk through this link ..,